# Making low voltage prettier/weatherproof?

Tags: electrical, low-voltage, stucco, coaxial-cable

I've got a big hole in my exterior wall where several coax and (old) phone cables punch through. It's just... there in the stucco. All of my low voltage wires are just hanging out on the outside wall too and I'd like to clean it up/weatherproof everything a bit.

I will eventually be running ethernet through the wall there as well (the hole's already there so why not) so I didn't just want to seal it up with caulk and walk away. So I have a couple of questions:

- Would putting a LB connector or exterior box over the hole in my wall and then running some PVC conduit back to the cable company box be against any kind of national code?
- If I use an LB can I mount it sideways as long as I'm caulking behind it and using watertight conduit?
- Do conduit straps/surface-mount box screws have to penetrate the wall to a stud or can they just go into the stucco?
- I've got one coax run (exiting the cable company box midway on left side) running up to the second floor, pretty close to the electrical weatherhead. Is there a keep out zone I should be aware of if I wanted to put that cable in conduit as well?

[image: Hole in my wall]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd slap up a 6" box, maybe PVC with threaded entries, and then use weathertight screw-in cable clamps to bring each data cable into the box.

And I'd either glue and caulk the back of the box to the wall... or have conduit go through the wall from that box, and fill the rest of the hole.  My concern is animals or insects using the hole as a superhighway.

Comment: So something like [this 2 gang box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-3-4-in-2-Gang-5-Holes-Weatherproof-Box-Gray-WDB575G/300846319?MERCH=REC-_-pipinstock-_-300846371-_-300846319-_-N) and a couple of [these clamps](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-4-in-Service-Entrance-SE-Water-Tight-Uf-Connector-90662/100131217) on the bottom?

I assume these [tapcon screws](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tapcon-3-16-in-x-1-3-4-in-Hex-Washer-Head-Concrete-Anchors-75-Pack-24305/100201596) could be used to secure the box to the wall with some caulk behind/around it to waterproof.

Comment: @RoscoePyell Yeah, that'd be fine if it's big enough.  My experience buying those styles of weatherproof boxes and clamps is that you're really better off going to the electrical supply on both price and availability.  Home Depot won't have it, or won't be able to find it if the computer says they have it.  They suck at obscura.   OTOH if you're mail-ordering, HD is the top choice.